# How do you solve this to $x$? $y = \frac{3}{4}x^2 -\frac{1}{4}x^3$

Tags: calculus, probability, functions, probability-distributions

I'm curious if there is any reasonable / not too complicated way of solving this because it was a task from an exam and I failed solving it without any helping tools (all I had was a normal calculator)?

I had to solve this to $x$ because I was supposed to take its inverse since the task originally asked us to generate a random variable from a density function. This function here is from the distribution function, and I'm trying to take its inverse and bringing the $x$ on the left hand side such that there is no other $x$ on the right hand side.

$$y = \frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^3$$

Here is one rough beginning (there are so many more attempts of mine but they have all ended up in nothing / wrong solutions and it would be too long to write them all here  :/ )

I always tried to reduce the degree of $x$ to make things easier but it doesn't really seem to help..

$$y = \frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^3 \Leftrightarrow y = x^2 \left(\frac{3}{4} -\frac{1}{4}x\right) \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{y} = x \cdot \sqrt{\frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{4}x}$$

And here I wouldn't know a way to continue to get to a solution buuhh :(

Are there any tricks that can help a lot here? Some formula, some substitution method or anything? All kind of help is very much appreciated!

**Edit: Adding density and distribution function because it was asked by @Semiclassical in the comments:**

Density function:
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{3}{4}\left(2x-x^2\right) & \textrm{for }  x \in \left(0,2\right)\\
           0 & \textrm{else} \end{array}\right.$$

Distribution function:

$$F(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^3 & \textrm{for }  0< x \leq 2 \\
1 & \textrm{for } x>2 \\
0 & \textrm{for } x<0
\end{array}\right.$$

The original task in the exam asked to generate a random variable from the density function.

Comment: [Cardano's Formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula) using $-\frac{1}{4}$ as $a$, $\frac{3}{4}$ as $b$, $0$ as $c$, and $-y$ as $d$.  Few people nowadays will bother memorizing the formula and even fewer bother proving it for themselves [though some advocate that we should](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc).  It certainly isn't easy to write down or use however in a short amount of time in an exam setting without considerable practice.

Comment: Have you graphed this? You see that the graph is an S-shaped cubic, and the associated real-valued function is not one-to-one. Thus there is no good way, once $y$ is given, of finding the associated $x$. As others have said, there is a cubic formula, which is certainly not the sort of thing that a sane teacher would ask you to make use of on an examination.

Comment: Given that you've tagged this as a probability problem, it would help to state the distribution of $X$ (assuming it was given).

Comment: @Semiclassical I have added them to my question now :) By the way, the density function was given but the distribution function was not given. I had to calculate it myself  on the way using the inversion method to simulate a random variable from the density function (that's what the original task was asking for). But the calculation is correct!

Comment: Ok. Then the upshot is that you're only really interested in $y=F(x)$ for $x\in [0,2]$. The resulting inverse function is then well-defined for $y\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admitting that you want to solve for $n$ the equation $$y = \frac{3}{4}x^2 -\frac{1}{4}x^3$$rewrite as a normal cubic equation in $x$ that is to say
$$x^3-3x^2+4y=0$$ and follow the steps described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) with $a=1$, $b=-3$, $c=0$ and $d=4y$.

You will get
$$\Delta=432y(1-y) \qquad p=-3 \qquad q=4y-2$$ If $\Delta >0$ that is to say $0 < y <1$, you will face three real roots and the best is to use the trigonometric method. So the roots will be given by
$$x_k=1+2 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}(1-2 y)\right) \qquad k=0,1,2$$

If $y<0$ or $y>1$, only one real root and the hyperbolic method would give for it
$$x=1-2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}(2 y-1)\right)$$

Comment: Within the probability context, it would seem that one can restrict to the case $0<y<1$ and then only consider the real root lying in the interval $[0,2]$. In particular one has $F(1)=1/2$, and one may check that $x_1=1$ when $y=1/2$. So the desired inverse should be $$x=F^{-1}(y) = 1+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac13 \cos^{-1}(1-2y)\right).$$